# How A Device Link To Driver In Linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, device-driver

Device file link to driver by major and minor number. So how drivers link to devices??? When we plug-in a device, how can kernel know it work with which module had loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers about vendor and device IDs and hotplug and udev are correct, but they haven't explained what major and minor numbers are. Just so all the keywords are covered for future searchers, I'll do that here.

Major and minor device numbers, as seen in `ls -l /dev`, don't contribute to the identification of a driver to be loaded on detection of a device. They are for the kernel to know what device you're accessing when you open the device file.

When a driver is loaded, if it supports any special files in `/dev`, it will call `register_chrdev` (or some similar function), notifying the kernel of the major number it wants to use. Some drivers dynamically choose a major number by asking the kernel to pick an unused one. The registration procedure puts the driver and its major number into a table where they can be found later.

Permanently allocated device numbers are registered with a central authority and the registrations are published in [Documentation/admin-guide/devices.*](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/devices.html).

Files in `/dev` have major numbers matching their driver, and minor numbers identifying a particular device or function. These files are created either statically by `MAKEDEV` or dynamically by the hotplug/udev system. The low-level "create device file" operation is called `mknod`.

When a user program opens a device file, the major and minor numbers are used to look up the driver in the table maintained by `register_chrdev`, and the driver's methods are called to service the user's requests.

Answer (score 1):

For PCI Devices, they expose a vendor and device id in a consistent location. Kernel modules can present to the pci subsystem a list of these that they support.

For example: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/uio/uio_aec.c#L48

Answer (score 0):

The [hotplug](http://linux-hotplug.sourceforge.net/) program may be automagically started by the kernel when it detects new plugged devices. Now [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) also contributes to that.